# Pycharm- How to set the background desktop of pycharm to translucent

Tags: pycharm

I want to set the background of pycharm tools to translucent. I want to look at the content of IDE doc when edit the code..., but I looked for half a day did not find how to set， can you tell me how to set it or pycharm have not this function?and how to set the width and color of line numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For ***line number*** color:

*Settings->Editor->Colors&Fonts->General->Code->Line number*

For ***gutter background***:

*Settings->Editor->Colors&Fonts->General->Editor->Gutter background*

Comment: As far as translucent IDE... I'm skeptical that you'll find this capability within PyCharm. You may have better luck forcing the app translucence from the OS terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any way to get a translucent window in PyCharm.

However, if you are just interested in a more interesting background, a good alternative might be this plugin, which displays a random background image from a folder and changes it every couple of minutes:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8502-background-image-plus